# PHP/MYSQL, removing an item from a list from a joining query, without deleting the item from the table.?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, sql

I have a query

```
SELECT products.productID, products.name, products.type, products.price, products.image_url
FROM  `products` 
JOIN `orders` ON products.productID = orders.productID
WHERE customerID = '$id'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

and I echoed out the result in a table form from a loop. now, how do I remove an item or a list without deleting it from the database, as in a shopping cart, where users can remove an item which wont be deleted from the table. 
THank you//

Comment: It depends on what your html table looks like.

Comment: You need to specify what record(s) you want deleted, and which record(s) you do not want deleted.  You say "remove an item or a list" - but you have no tables called "item" or "list" in your code example.

Comment: You should keep one flag in table like is_active, is_deleted. Using that flag you can set it to 0/1 for deleted/undeleted record.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your db schema, very difficult to guess. But it might look something like this:

```
DELETE FROM `order`
WHERE orders.productID = 456
AND orders.orderID = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a table that contains the shopping cart, which is separate from the tables that contain all the product details. When you delete rows from the shopping cart table, that doesn't affect the product table.

Comment: I was hoping of  a javascript solution where, it all processes on the client side.

Comment: If you want help with the client-side code, you need to post it.